# How to animate an User Control by Storyboard

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have an UserControl (UC) and use it within my MainPaige.xaml.cs like this:

```
var UC_test = new UC();
Content.Children.Add(UC_test);
Grid.SetRow(UC_test, 0);
```

And want to animate it like this:

```
sb_UC_test.Begin();
```

Here is the storyboard within the MainPaige.xaml:

```
<Storyboard x:Name="sb_UC_test">
    <DoubleAnimation 
        BeginTime="0:0:1"
        Duration="0:0:2" 
        From="0"
        To="1" 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UC_test.Opacity)" 
        Storyboard.TargetName="UC_test" 
        d:IsOptimized="True"/>
</Storyboard>
```

But it does not work.

Comment: I suspect this doesn't work because UC_test is not an existing element at runtime. I am not sure if doing `UC_test.Name = "UC_test";` would work.

Comment: does not work "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" - should I create the storyboard by c#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the target of your Storyboard dynamically from the C# code before starting it:

```
Storyboard.SetTarget(sb_UC_test, UC_test);
```

And remove the `Storyboard.TargetName` property from your XAML.

Comment: Ok I have it - the UserControl was at Opacity="0" and have to be at "1" - dont know why